# Minitoc numeration overlaps with subsection titles

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, horizontal-alignment, minitoc

I have long `minitoc` numeration depth `\setcounter{minitocdepth}{3}`. I have a problem with it:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{newcent}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\dominitoc
\nomtcrule
\setlength{\mtcindent}{5pt}
\setcounter{minitocdepth}{5}
\renewcommand{\mtcSfont}{\small\bfseries\rmfamily}
\renewcommand{\mtifont}{\large\bfseries\rmfamily}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\appendix
\chapter{X}
\minitoc
\newpage
\section{X}
\section{X}
\section{X}
\section{X}
\section{X}
\section{X}
\section{X}
\subsection{X}
\subsection{X}
\subsection{x}
\subsection{X}
\section{X}
\section{X}
\section{X}
\section{X}
\section{X}
\subsection{X}
\subsection{X}
\subsection{X}
\subsection{X}
\subsection{X}
\subsection{X}
\subsection{X}
\subsection{X}
\subsection{X}
\subsection{X}
\subsection{X}
\subsection{X}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see `A.12.10` overlaps with `X`.

How I can change setting of `minitoc` to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a [`minitoc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/minitoc)-specific problem. Adding

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@subsection{\@dottedtocline{2}{3.8em}{3.5em}}% Used to be {3.8em}{3.2em}
\makeatother
```

to your document preamble increases the width allocated to the subsection number in the ToC-related files from `3.2em` to `3.5em`. You can adjust this length to suit your needs.

[image]

Comment: the disadvantage is that, if you happen to have enough subsections so that the number before the X is, say, 12.100, you'll get another overlap. but this scenario is unlikely to happen, I guess.

Comment: @araruna: Hence the fact that I mention "adjust this length to suit your needs". If your needs call for `A.12.100`, then adjust `3.5em` to something higher.

Comment: I had to dig deep to find this. Thanks very much !