# Replacement minitoc package style by KOMA-script possibilities

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, tocstyle, tocbasic

I have a long document which uses the KOMA-Script book class scrbook and I would like to add a part-level and chapter-level table of contents, as it is shown on figures below:

[image: Chapter-level TOC in twocolumn page layout]

It works, but KOMA complains about many things:

*1. Issue: KOMA-Script together with Minitoc package*

```
(scrbook)              with a KOMA-Script class is not recommended.
(scrbook)              Nevertheless, using requested
(scrbook)              package `minitoc' on input line 67
```

*2. Issue \bprot@dottedtocline*

```
Class scrbook Warning: usage of `\bprot@dottedtocline' is deprecated.
```

Can be replaced code below with KOMA-script possibilites, so it would be possible to **remove** package **minitoc** from project?

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[open=any, titlepage=false, twocolumn, fontsize=10pt,]{scrbook}

  \usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
  \usepackage{blindtext}
  % ===========================
  %    My KOMA setting 
  % ===========================
  % http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51867/
   \usepackage{scrhack}                      % KOMA warning about ToC
   \usepackage{xcolor}

  % ---- Part -----------------------------------------------------
  % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102303/
  % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110092/
    \newcommand*\partcolor{\color{blue}}% Part is coloured blue
    \renewcommand*\partformat    
      {\partcolor\partname~\thepart\if@altsecnumformat.\fi}

  % Adjusting spacing around section subsection titles with koma script
  % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/223508/
  % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43087/
    \RedeclareSectionCommand[
      beforeskip=-1sp,
      afterskip=2\baselineskip
    ]{chapter}

   \RedeclareSectionCommand[
     beforeskip=-\baselineskip,
     afterskip=.5\baselineskip
   ]{section}

  \RedeclareSectionCommand[
    beforeskip=-.75\baselineskip,
    afterskip=.5\baselineskip
  ]{subsection}

 \RedeclareSectionCommand[
   beforeskip=-.5\baselineskip,
   afterskip=.25\baselineskip
 ]{subsubsection}


 % Table fo content  TOC   
 % ---------------------     
 % the tocbasic package style selected and conﬁgured with DeclareTOCStyleEntry
 \KOMAoptions{toc=chapterentrydotfill}

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[%
  dynnumwidth=true,%
   % numwidth=3.5em, 
       indent=3em, 
   beforeskip=1em
]{tocline}{part} % scrguien page 357

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  dynnumwidth=true,
   % numwidth=2em, 
   beforeskip=1em
]{tocline}{chapter}

% ---- Table fo content for each chapter------------
% minitoc.pdf: If used, the hyperref package must be loaded before minitoc. 
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/334007
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/268205
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167390
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/164308/
\let\cleardoublepage=\clearpage  % Remove blank page after TOC and title page
\usepackage[nohints,tight]{minitoc}   % formatting table of contents.
  \mtcsettitle{minitoc}{ }        % sets title or empty title (i.e. no title)
  \mtcsettitle{parttoc}{Obsah} 
  % Vertical gap before part-level mini-tables titles. Default: 50pt
  \renewcommand\mtcgapbeforeheads{0pt}  
  % Vertical gap after part-level mini-tables titles. Default: 40pt   
  \renewcommand\mtcgapafterheads{0pt}
 \mtcsetrules{minitoc}{off}           
 \mtcsetoffset{minitoc}{-0.5em}
 \setlength{\mtcindent}{-0.5em}           % sets the indentation of the toc
 \mtcsetfeature{minitoc}{open}{\vspace{1mm}}

% onecolumn table of contents & minitoc in twocolumn document:
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151320/
\newcommand{\dochaptertoc}{%
  \vspace{-1.5\baselineskip} % workaround for removed rule
  \smash{\makebox[\linewidth]{\hrulefill}} % workaround for removed rule
  \vspace{-2.5\baselineskip} % workaround for removed rule
  \minitoc
  \vspace{-1.15\baselineskip} % workaround for removed rule
  \smash{\makebox[\linewidth]{\hrulefill}} % workaround for removed rule
  \vspace{-0.5\baselineskip} % workaround for removed rule
}

\newcommand{\setchaptertoc}{%
  \setchapterpreamble{% KOMA-Script command 
  \dochaptertoc%
  }
}  
% The KOMA -Script package tocstyle
% -------------------------------------
% How to increase the numwidth for a part in ToC?
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119849/
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63856/
% With option tocindentauto all widths at the TOCs are calc. by tocstyle.
\usepackage[tocindentauto, tocgraduated]{tocstyle}
\usetocstyle{KOMAlike}

\makeatletter
  \renewcommand*{\raggedchapterentry}{\setlength{\@tempdima}{3em}}
  \renewcommand*\l@part{\bprot@dottedtocline{-1}{1.5em}{4.5em}}
  \renewcommand*\l@section{\bprot@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{3.5em}}
  \renewcommand*\l@subsection{\bprot@dottedtocline{2}{3.8em}{4em}}
  \renewcommand*\l@subsubsection{\bprot@dottedtocline{3}{7.0em}{4.1em}}
  \renewcommand*\l@paragraph{\bprot@dottedtocline{4}{10em}{5em}}
  \renewcommand*\l@subparagraph{\bprot@dottedtocline{5}{12em}{6em}}
  \def\@pnumwidth{3em}  % default 1.55
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{-1} % 
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}           % Number subsubsections in the chapters
\setcounter{parttocdepth}{0} 
\doparttoc
\setcounter{minitocdepth}{2} 
\dominitoc
\tableofcontents

\setcounter{page}{3000}  
\setcounter{chapter}{100}
\setcounter{part}{5080}

\setchaptertoc 

\part{Part I}
\parttoc
  \chapter{My chapter I}
    \section{My first section}  
      \blindtext
        \subsection{My first subsection}
          \blindtext  
    \section{My second section}
        \blindtext 
  \chapter{My chapter II}
  \chapter{My chapter II}
  \chapter{My chapter III}
  \chapter{My chapter IV}
  \chapter{My chapter V}
  \chapter{My chapter VI}
  \chapter{My chapter VII}
  \chapter{My chapter VIII}
  \chapter{My chapter IX}
  \chapter{My chapter X}
  \chapter{My chapter XI}
  \chapter{My chapter XII}
  \chapter{My chapter XIII}
  \chapter{My chapter XIV}
  \chapter{My chapter XV}
  \chapter{My chapter XVI}
  \chapter{My chapter XVII}
  \chapter{My chapter XVIII}
  \chapter{My chapter XIX}
  \chapter{My chapter XX}
  \chapter{My chapter XXI}
  \chapter{My chapter XXII}
  \chapter{My chapter XXIII}
  \chapter{My chapter XXIV}
  \chapter{My chapter XXVI}
  \chapter{My chapter XXVII}
  \chapter{My chapter XXVIII}
  \chapter{My chapter XXIX}
  \chapter{My chapter XXX}
\part{Part II}
\parttoc
  \chapter{My chapter I}
    \section{My first section}  
      \blindtext
        \subsection{My first subsection}
            \blindtext  
    \section{My second section}
        \blindtext 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Remove package `tocstyle` from your code. Replace the `\bprot@dottedtocline` code using either `\RedeclareSectionCommand` or `\DeclareTOCStyleEntry`. Maybe package `etoc` can be used to get local ToCs in chapters and parts.

Comment: @esdd No solution with tocbasic package? I found https://komascript.de/node/2107, but I don't understand it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a suggestion that bases on the answer of @Schweinebacke to [Create section-level toc in a KOMA-script document that already uses minitoc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/359758/43317) and on my answer to [How to write a minitoc with plain KOMA-script?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/502077/43317) It needs at least KOMA-Script version 3.27 (provides hooks which can be used by `\AddtoOneTimeDoHook` or `\AddtoDoHook`).

```latex
\documentclass[fontsize=10pt,open=any,twocolumn]{scrbook}[2019/10/12]% needs version 3.27 or newer
\providecommand*{\Ifstr}{\ifstr}% added because of changes in upcoming KOMA-Script version 3.28 and \ifstr replaced by \Ifstr in the code (see https://komascript.de/faq_deprecatedif) 
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{scrwfile}% avoid trouble with the limited number of write handles
\usepackage{xpatch}

\colorlet{partcolor}{blue}
\addtokomafont{partprefix}{\color{partcolor}}% change color of part prefix
\addtokomafont{part}{\normalcolor}% use normal color for part title
%\renewcommand*\partformat{\partname~\thepart}% if you want to remove \autodot from the definition
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  tocdynnumwidth=true,%
  tocbeforeskip=1em,
  tocindent=1.5em
]{part}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=0pt,
  afterindent=false,
  afterskip=2\baselineskip,
  tocdynnumwidth,
  tocbeforeskip=1em plus 1pt minus 1pt,% add some glue
  toclinefill=\TOCLineLeaderFill
]{chapter}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=\baselineskip,
  afterindent=false,
  afterskip=.5\baselineskip,
  tocindent=1.5em,
  tocnumwidth=3.5em
]{section}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=.75\baselineskip,
  afterindent=false,
  afterskip=.5\baselineskip,
  tocindent=3.8em,
  tocnumwidth=4em
]{subsection}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=.5\baselineskip,
  afterindent=false,
  afterskip=.25\baselineskip,
  tocindent=7em,
  tocnumwidth=4.1em
]{subsubsection}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  tocindent=10em,
  tocnumwidth=5em
]{paragraph}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  tocindent=12em,
  tocnumwidth=6em
]{subparagraph}

\RedeclareSectionCommands
  [tocpagenumberwidth=3em]
  {part,chapter,section,subsection,paragraph,subparagraph}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/359758
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/502077
\makeatletter
\newif\ifuseparttoc
\newcommand*{\parttoc}[1][\thepart]{% new command to generate and show a chapter toc
  \useparttoctrue% switch on part-toc-entries
  \edef\ext@parttoc{tcp#1}% extension of the part-toc-file, e.g., tcpI
  \DeclareNewTOC[
    listname=Obsah,
    %unset=onecolumn% if the part toc should use twocolumn
  ]{\ext@parttoc}% declare a new toc file
  \begingroup
    \value{tocdepth}=\chaptertocdepth% we want entries down to chapter
    \listoftoc{\ext@parttoc}% show the toc with header
  \endgroup
}
\xapptocmd\addtocentrydefault{% patch the KOMA-Script's generic toc entry generator
  \ifuseparttoc% if part toc entries should be generated
    \expandafter\tocbasic@addxcontentsline\expandafter{\ext@parttoc}{#1}{#2}{#3}% do it
  \fi
}{}{}
\xpretocmd\part{\useparttocfalse}{}{}% entries in part toc are automatically switched off at start of \part
\newif\ifusechaptertoc% Switch to tell \addtocentrydefault to not only make entries to the toc-file but also to the current section-toc-file
\newcommand*{\chaptertoc}[2][\thechapter]{% new command to generate and show a chapter toc
  \usechaptertoctrue% switch on chapter-toc-entries
  \edef\ext@chaptoc{tcc#1}% extension of the chapter-toc-file, e.g., tcc1
  \DeclareNewTOC{\ext@chaptoc}% declare a new toc file
  %\addsec*{Contents}% header of the chaptertoc
  \setchapterpreamble{%
    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
      \hrulefill\par
      \value{tocdepth}=\subsectiontocdepth% we want entries down to subsection
      \listoftoc*{\ext@chaptoc}% show the toc without header
    \end{minipage}%
    \par\bigskip\nobreak\noindent\hrulefill\par
    \bigskip\noindent\ignorespaces% add some vertical space after the toc and do not indent the following text
  }%
}
\xapptocmd\addtocentrydefault{% patch the KOMA-Script's generic toc entry generator
  \ifusechaptertoc% if chapter toc entries should be generated
    \Ifstr{#1}{chapter}{}
      {\expandafter\tocbasic@addxcontentsline\expandafter{\ext@chaptoc}{#1}{#2}{#3}}% do it
  \fi
}{}{}
\xpretocmd\chapter{\usechaptertocfalse}{}{}% entries in chapter toc are automatically switched off at start of \chapter
\xpretocmd\part{\usechaptertocfalse}{}{}% entries in chapter toc are automatically switched off at start of \part
\makeatother

\newcommand\setchaptertoc[1][]{%
  \Ifstr{#1}{}
    {\AddtoOneTimeDoHook{heading/preinit/chapter}{\chaptertoc}}
    {\AddtoOneTimeDoHook{heading/preinit/chapter}{\chaptertoc[#1]}}%
}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{\partnumdepth}% depth of TOC
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\setcounter{page}{3000}
\setcounter{chapter}{100}
\setcounter{part}{5080}

\part{Part I}
\parttoc

\setchaptertoc
\chapter{My chapter I}
\section{My first section}
\blindtext
\subsection{My first subsection}
\blindtext
\section{My second section}
\blindtext

\chapter{My chapter II}
\chapter{My chapter II}
\chapter{My chapter III}
\chapter{My chapter IV}
\chapter{My chapter V}
\chapter{My chapter VI}
\chapter{My chapter VII}
\chapter{My chapter VIII}
\chapter{My chapter IX}
\chapter{My chapter X}
\chapter{My chapter XI}
\chapter{My chapter XII}
\chapter{My chapter XIII}
\chapter{My chapter XIV}
\chapter{My chapter XV}
\chapter{My chapter XVI}
\chapter{My chapter XVII}
\chapter{My chapter XVIII}
\chapter{My chapter XIX}
\chapter{My chapter XX}
\chapter{My chapter XXI}
\chapter{My chapter XXII}
\chapter{My chapter XXIII}
\chapter{My chapter XXIV}
\chapter{My chapter XXVI}
\chapter{My chapter XXVII}
\chapter{My chapter XXVIII}
\chapter{My chapter XXIX}
\chapter{My chapter XXX}

\part{Part II}
\parttoc
\setchaptertoc
\chapter{My chapter I}
\section{My first section}
\blindtext
\subsection{My first subsection}
  \blindtext
\section{My second section}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Additional remark: I have used your settings in e.g. `\l@section` for the `tocindent`s and `tocnumwidth`s. But I think, you have to adjust them, if you change `tocdepth` for the chapter tocs to e.g. `\subsubsectiontocdepth`.

Result:

[image]

Comment: You are »incroyable«.